# How would you <read><read aloud><pronounce> "2+3=5"?

Tags: phrase-choice

(1) How would you read "2+3=5"?

(2) How would you read aloud "2+3=5"?

(3) How would you pronounce "2+3=5"?

[Question] Which sentence sounds natural? If none sounds natural, What should I say?

Comment: They're all fine. Number 2 has a variant: "How would you read "2+3=5" aloud?

Comment: "pronounce" is a little less likely than the other two, unless the question is about precisely what noises would you make when speaking one or more of the words you'd use.

Comment: @Jaime Thank you, Jaime.

Comment: There is also "How would you say 2+3=5"

Comment: @PeterJennings. Thank you, Peter Jennings.

Answer (score 2):

Those are all possible. Number 2 has a variant: "How would you read "2+3=5" aloud? Or you might just use "How would you say...".

It would be quite rare. People don't normally speak mathematical formulae out loud, and if they do, they normally don't need to ask about the pronunciation.
Ironically, if you can ask the question out loud, you must already know the answer.

Your suggestion, "read", is clearly influenced by the Japanese term "reading" of kanji. On the other hand, "pronounce" suggests that you are asking about the details of which particular vowel and consonant sounds are used.

In English the question of "which phonetic value should be given to a symbol?" doesn't often occur.

Comment: Thank you, James. Please assume that the equation "2+3=5" is written on a sheet of paper and that I'm pointing at it. Can I say "How would you say this?"?

Comment: Possible, but very rare in practice. Pretty much everyone who could form the question already knows the words "two" and "plus", and in more complex formulae are not normally spoken aloud at all. You don't read maths out loud, except in the most simple cases.

Comment: I've marked this answer up, but I'd quibble about such sentences being very rare.  I'm pretty sure my son (a native English speaker learning maths through German) has actually asked me a very similar question fairly recently.  He was confused about what person of the verb to use (is or are, equals or equal). My non-native speaker partner has certainly asked the very same question (albeit a long time ago)!

Comment: "People don't normally speak mathematical formulae out loud" 
I do essentially every single day as a math tutor.
"they normally don't need to ask about the pronunciation."
The people I tutor, and students learning a new symbol often need to ask about how something is read. If you're learning about "∇⨯F", you need to know that it's read "curl F" or "del cross F" and not "upside down triangle thingy times F".

Comment: @MarkS.  Being a maths tutor isn't normal people!  (I teach maths myself!)  Things like "curl" are technical and not part of regular English. Like most technical language, if you need it, you'll learn it.  But I stand by my point,  maths is to be written, not spoken.  When a teacher or tutor reads maths, it should normally be supported by a visual representation. The odd thing about the question is that in order to ask the question, you need to know the answer!

Comment: "I stand by my point, maths is to be written, not spoken." This is a really odd claim to me. There are tons of language-learning books that explain the differences in how mathematical equations and unit symbols etc. are read out loud, so that people can talk about splitting the bill and home renovations and have other technical conversations. And I don't think questions like "how is something intended to be read?" are that uncommon for native speakers (e.g. "how do you read that sign ['Madrag']?"), to say nothing about learners of English a second language.